# Makefile errors in Solaris when using conditional assignment

Tags: makefile, solaris

I have encountered errors on running the conditional assignment operator in a Makefile in Solaris 11.1. However I encounter no errors on running the same Makefile in Ubuntu.

```
version ?= 6.1
all:
    echo $(version)
```

<sup>Note: Before the echo, there is a tab before the `echo` in the original code. Using four spaces here just for convenience of editing.</sup>

Error encountered in Solaris 11.1:

```
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 1: Badly formed macro assignment
```

However, there are no such errors on Ubuntu.

Comment: Solaris does not use GNU make.  Don't use GNU make extensions if your makefile must be portable to other versions of make.  Or install and use GNU make on Solaris.

Answer (score 4):

Better you use `gmake` because many Makefiles use Gnu-specific features. Solaris make might be using slightly different syntax. You can read the [Solaris makefile manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9l0/index.html); you will find that there is no `?=` operator in it. Hence you are getting that error.

Comment: Can you post `make --version` ? if the problem still persists

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, the Solaris OS uses the gmake utility instead of make.

Comment: What is `make --version` giving?

Comment: make --version throws a fatal error, however gmake --version shows:   GNU MAKE - 3.82

Comment: @animesh.. sorry i don't know much about gmake. As far as I know gmake is GNU make which follows http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html syntax. Your code must work with it then.

Comment: BDW, I had one question. How you are running the makefile? `$~ gmake` ?

Comment: gmake -f path/to/the/makefile

Answer (score 3):

`?=` is a feature added by GNU make, which is the default version of make on Ubuntu, but on Solaris is installed as `gmake` or `/usr/gnu/bin/make`.   `?=` is not supported by the native make command on Solaris, which is installed as `/usr/ccs/bin/make` on older releases, `/usr/bin/make` on Solaris 11 and later.

If you need to use the GNU extensions in your makefiles, make sure you run the GNU make, not the Solaris make.